# events responding slow when using multiple components in one component - angular5

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is Dashboard component which using multiple components from different modules 
when i fire any event from imported component it takes time to trigger.

```
<div class="lffeedbox">
  <srv-create-post (postmessage)="saveLiveFeedPost($event)"></srv-create-post>
    <div>
      <srv-post-feed [LiveFeedInput]="LiveFeeds" [ShowHidden]='showhidden'></srv-post-feed>
    </div>

    <srv-loading [visible]="LiveFeedsloading"></srv-loading>
       <div class="well well-small clearfix group_content no_upcomming" *ngIf="LiveFeeds?.length==0 && !LiveFeedsloading" style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
          {{'No_record_to_display'|translate}}
       </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <aside class="sidebaritems">
      <srv-feed-categories [activeIndex]='typeID' (SetPostFilterType)="setPostFilterType($event)"></srv-feed-categories>
      <srv-break-room></srv-break-room>
      <srv-people-near-you></srv-people-near-you>
      <srv-recent-articles></srv-recent-articles>
      <srv-latest-snaps></srv-latest-snaps>
      <srv-groups-may-like></srv-groups-may-like>
   </aside>
</div>`
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more input. How long does it take? Which browser do you use?

Comment: It there are more components then it takes more time to load , like header side bar, but when i enter to other page which has less html that sidebar opening quickly , i m using lazy loading as well